# How to view personal Google+ profile badge at Windows XP

Tags: html, google-plus, badge

I was following [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) to view my Google+ profile badge on the custom starting screen on my Firefox.

Starting screen is a html-document stored on my desktop and viewed with file:// -originating URL. My browser is Firefox 16 and Windows is XP.

I have read that people have problems with their XP´s to show the badge but nobody seems to have the solution.

Anybody succeeded on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `http://` on the first line.

...`data-href="http://plus.google.com/`... instead of ...`data-href="//plus.google.com/`...

Here's a short explanation about leaving it protocolless in an otherwise unrealated article: http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/#protocolless